# Plugin opens only after two clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a custom made tooltip plugin which should be opened by another plugin. But the plugin opens only after the second click and I can't figure out what the problem is.

The whole thing can be tested under. You have to click on the second input Field.

```
https://codepen.io/magic77/pen/XWMeqrM
```

```
$.fn.packstationFinder = function (options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        event: 'click.packstationFinder'
    }, options);

    this.bind(settings.event, function (e) {
        if ($postalCode.val() === '') {
            $('#packstation-number').tooltip();
            
            return;
        }
    });

    return this;
};

$('[rel~=packstationFinder]').packstationFinder();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the code in Codepen. The problem here is because in `packstationFinder()` you call the `tooltip()` function for the element. But as you can see inside the `tooltip()` you just bind the click event on the element and not trigger it. So by current code with a first click on the element (`#packstation-number`) you just bind the click event and really trigger the tooltip only by the second click. You can see that it work as it should by moving out the calling of tooltip() function from packstationFinder() and call it directly as in the code below:

```
$.fn.packstationFinder = function (options) {
var settings = $.extend({
    event: 'click.packstationFinder'
}, options);

return this;
};

$('[rel~=packstationFinder]').packstationFinder();
$('#packstation-number').tooltip();
```

Comment: ah yes you're right. Thanks for the explanation. Another side effect is that calling one plugin from the other triggers "triggeroutside" function multiple times when clicking on the element again and again. is there any advise how to call plugin from other plugin?

Comment: If my answer was useful for you, please, mark it as an answer and upvote it. 
Regarding the side effects not sure that I can give you particular advice, but maybe you should consider change the logic a bit and do not initiate one plugin from another.